# Is there a design pattern for a repository that always returns a single object?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository-pattern, ddd-repositories

I'm developing an application which translates objects from another API into my own types and back. I've exposed this functionality through a number of repository classes which are passed a `Document` object from the API I'm working with. All the repository classes are based off the following interface.

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : INamed
{
    void Add(T toAdd);
    T Get(string name);
    IDictionary<string, T> GetAll();
    ICollection<string> GetNames();
    void Update(T toUpdate);
    void Delete(string name);
}
```

Where `INamed` just forces entities to have a `Name` property, as each is identified by a unique name in a `Document`.

```
public interface INamed
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

However, a `Document` also contains a number of settings/attribute objects for which there will be only one instance per document. These types thus do not have a name in the document to identify them. Yet, I still want to create some kind of generic interface for getting/setting these objects from/to a `Document`.

The simple interface I want to use is below. But I don't like that I used the word "Repository" in the name, as that implies a collection of items in my mind.

```
public interface ISingleItemRepository<T>
{
    T Get();
    void Set(T item);
}
```

Does this look like some other common design pattern with a different name?

Comment: Sounds like a _property bag_. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa768197(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The word "Repository" suggests an object responsible for the persistence of other objects. I wouldn't really think of whether for some business reasons the repository is somewhat specific in a sense your document repository is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IoC containers like Unity use the term [**Lifetime Manager**](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/blob/master/source/Unity/Src/Lifetime/LifetimeManager.cs) for such things (i.e. SingletonLifetimeManager). Not a pattern but rather a naming convention...